# Loopback + AndroidSDK: Retrieving Date fields

Tags: android, mysql, api, datetime, loopbackjs

I have a working Loopback API running as a backend for an Android app. I'm using MySQL to save the data. All the tables have at least one DateTime field. Of course, I need to retrieve them.

Using the API explorer I correctly get these DateTime fields:

```
    {
        "id": 1,
        ...
        "DtDateAdded": "2014-06-10T16:42:36.000Z",
        "DtLastModified": "2014-10-01T00:00:00.000Z"
    }
```

So the date fields are correctly retrieved from the DB.

But when I retrieve the data from the Android app, date fields are null.

This is the model definition:

```
public class MyModel extends Model {

    private int Id;
    private Date DtLastModified;

    public int getId() {
        return Id;
    }

    public void setId(int Id) {
        this.Id = Id;
    }

    public Date getDtLastModified() {
        return DtLastModified;
    }

    public void setDtLastModified(Date DtLastModified) {
        this.DtLastModified = DtLastModified;
    }
}
```

The code to retrieve the data:

```
repository.findAll(new ListCallback<MyModel>() {

    @Override
    public void onSuccess(List<MyModel> list) {
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            MyModel objREST = list.get(i);
            Log.i("Tour ID", objREST.getId() + "Last Modified: " + objREST.getDtLastModified());
        }
    }
}
```

The log outputs the Id field correctly but the date field is null.

Answer (score 0):

The Loopback Android SDK currently does not support "advanced" data types.

Dates are represented as strings in JSON: "2015-03-24T18:00:09.975Z". You need to create a setter which accepts an String and converts it (probably by using an external Date/Time library).